# How to start/stop Runnable/Handler?

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I'm trying to maintain databases synchronized between a Webservice and Android app.
The code below is working, but I encounter some problems:

- Every time I go to main page of App a new infinite process is started.
- The process never ends

Can anyone explain how to start and stop this process as I wish?
I want this process to run every 5 minutes, but only once and when the app is open.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // DO WORK
            Mantenimiento();
            // Call function.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000000);
        }
    };
    r.run();
}
```

Comment: use removeCallback. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: you can stop **Handler** by using this **handler.removeCallbacks();**

Comment: but i need to stop it from onDestroy

Comment: And where is the problem to call `handler.removeCallbacks()` in onDestroy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either use TimerTask:

http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/
http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/

or

can take Boolean and run the loop while boolean is true and make sleep to other thread and while leaving app make Boolean false.

Comment: Using the TimerTask I can control the task. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use java Timers in Android. They are not reliable. Handlers are the Timer equivalents in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Every 5 Minutes? Do you even know what `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000000);` does? It starts the runnable every 16.7 minutes. It's not very difficult to find out how to convert minutes to milliseconds.

`handler.removeCallbacks()` and the boolean variable which you would check before `postDelayed()` were already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

would use this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Thread r = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            // DO WORK
            Mantenimiento();
            // Call function.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000000);
        }
    };
    r.start(); // THIS IS DIFFERENT
}
```